# What is the concept behind creating instance of TransactionScope which uses DependentTransaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, transactionscope

I would like to ask about DependentTransaction aspects, the following code got from MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.dependenttransaction

```
private static void WorkerThread(object transaction)
{
    //Create a DependentTransaction from the object passed to the WorkerThread
    DependentTransaction dTx = (DependentTransaction)transaction;

    //Sleep for 1 second to force the worker thread to delay
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    //Pass the DependentTransaction to the scope, so that work done in the scope becomes part of the transaction passed to the worker thread
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(dTx))
    {
        //Perform transactional work here.

        //Call complete on the transaction scope
        ts.Complete();
    }

    //Call complete on the dependent transaction
    dTx.Complete();
}
```

why would we need to create an instance of TransactionScope again where it uses DependentTransaction? Wouldn't be enough just to depend on DependentTransaction and to call DependentTransaction.Complete()?

Answer (score 0):

TransactionScope creates the actual consructor for the Transaction ( 1 Transaction Constructor:Many Transactions). DependentTransaction is kind of different in that it relies on usage of the scope TransactionScope to end before that specific Transaction can complete. Meaning pretty much 1 or many transactions will complete after destruction. Try using directive Transactions, and then creating a DependentTransaction object. The rest should be self-explanatory.